# readf error when trying to use Synergy

Tags: linux, macos, synergy

As of a few hours ago, I have had an issue getting my Linux synergy server to connect to my Mac client. Both are running the newest version of Synergy and I have ensured that the passwords for encryption are the same. The most confusing part is that if I set my Mac as the host and Ubuntu as the client, it works correctly.

Here is the debug output I see on my Mac when it is the client:

```
NOTE: connecting to '10.60.146.49': 10.60.146.49:24800
INFO: crypto mode: cfb
DEBUG1: connecting to server
DEBUG1: connected;  wait for hello
DEBUG2: readf(Synergy%2i%2i)
DEBUG2: readf: format mismatch: S vs $
DEBUG: retry in 1 seconds
WARNING: failed to connect to server: Protocol error from server
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the legacy encryption protocol. Actually the legacy encryption has now been removed. Please try using the latest version which uses SSL encryption instead.